# Use TYPO3 ckeditor in frontend

Tags: ckeditor, typo3

Is it possible to use the same ckeditor that TYPO3 (8.7.11) uses in the frontend too? 
I have to implement a user form with an editor and I want the frontend user to see exactly the result that is displayed in the backend - so I need to use the same editor.

Is there a way to use the same editor without installing the ckeditor plugin a second time? Maybe any functions to easily include it or something?

Comment: CKEditor.js ist here: `sysext/rte_ckeditor/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Contrib/ckeditor.js`. I don't know how to implement in FE. I tried to implements it via Controller, but that failed. - Let me know, if you found a solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already configured the CK-Editor it should be only a matter of creating something like this in your Template:

```html
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
            <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
            <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                    This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
                </textarea>
                <script>
                    // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                    // instance, using default configuration.
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                </script>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The ckeditor.js should be inside your Typo3-source-folder under:
`typo3/sysext/rte_ckeditor/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Contrib/ckeditor.js`

The code-example is taken from the CKEditor 4 Dokumentation which can be found here:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/index.html

EDIT:

After testing this Code myself, I noticed that this does not work since the Typo3-Installation of CKEditor is missing the `style.js-file` which includes the 
style-definition.

I downloaded the standard version of CKEditor from here:
https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/
And inserted the `style.js-file` (located at the root level of the folder) in the same directory my `ckeditor.js` is located.

After adding the file, including this Code:

```html
        <script src="/typo3/sysext/rte_ckeditor/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Contrib/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <form>
                <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                    This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
                </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
        </form>
```

inside of any Template shoud add the ck-editor.